# why the intersection of an infinite neighbourhoods of a number could not be still a neighbourhood for that number?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying in depth neighbourhoods of numbers and I have the following observation "The intersection of a finite neighbourhoods of a number x from R is a neighbourhood of x, but the intersection of an infinite number of neighbourhoods of x **could not** be a neighbourhood of x."

Now the question is why an infinite neighbourhoods of a number **could not** be a neighbourhood of that number considering that a finite neighbourhoods of a number withoud doubt is a neighbourhood of that number?

Comment: Consider $I_n := (-1/n , 1/n)$ and compute $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$.

Comment: Possibly a language ambiguity: "*could not* be" or "could *not be*" ?

Answer (score 3):

The intersection of infinitely many nbhds of a real number **can** be a nbhd: for instance,

$$\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\left(-1-\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right)=[-1,1]$$

is a (closed) nbhd of $0$ that is the intersection of infinitely many (open) nbhds of $0$. For that matter, let

$$I_n=\left(-1-\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right)$$

for $n\ge 1$, and let $I_0=(-1,1)$; then $\bigcap_{n\ge 0}I_n=(-1,1)$, so here we have an intersection of infinitely many open nbhds of $0$ that is even an **open** nbhd of $0$.

The correct statement is that the intersection of infinitely many nbhds of a real number **need not** be a nbhd of that number. It **can** be, but in general it is not.